# How to integrate an Angular 4 app with a Spring Boot stack?

Tags: java, spring, angular, rest, spring-mvc

i would like to integrate an Angular 4 client app with a Java Spring application working on `http://localhost:8080/` and offering some Rest endpoints.
My goal is to be able to call the Angular app from a url like `http://localhost:8080/adminisitration`. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to prod build your ng app and place that in spring-boot folder:

1. Create a public folder under resources in your spring-boot project
2. `ng build --prod`, type this command on you angular project which will create a dist folder under your angular project directory
3. Copy files from you dist folder and place it in public folder under resources of your spring-boot project.

This will help you run your angular-app under spring-boot.

Then hit http://localhost:8080/adminisitration, it should work fine

Comment: Your solution sounds easy and do exactly what I want!
But how to _point_ the app to `http://localhost:8080/adminisitration`?
You're just adding the app to the ressource folder.

Comment: What's your entry point for ng is it index.html? If so you would be having a button or so for going forward or may be the same page as your admin with login options

Comment: Thank you! It works. But I had to change the `href` attribute of the `base` tag in `index.html`

Comment: "ng build --prod", not "ng-build --prod"

Comment: In my Angular tutorial, I serve the page by typing 'ng serve' on the command line. Does Spring Boot replace this? Or do I need to serve the client and the server separately?

Comment: @AkshaySrivastava I am trying to follow your instructions. I did create a folder named web under resouces and pasted my dist folder content. Later when i run my application, i dont any page served: Please throw some light on this. Do i need to change my index.html? or any other setting required?

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways first is that you serve angular app from your spring boot application as static resources so you need to pack it into jar and that's not easy when you have two different repositories for frontend and backend and doesn't look to good from maintenance point of view.

Second is that you have angular static resources on nginx and spring boot app is reachable to angular thru reverse proxy configured on nginx like

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api/;
}
```

So when angular asks for `GET http://localhost/api/somerest` it forwards it to `GET http://localhost:8080/api/somerest`

Comment: If using webpack, proxy config is similar: [webpack proxy](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to serve an angular front-end from a spring-boot application , is to have a multi-module project. Then automate the build process to copy the dist folder from  the ui module into the service module during `maven clean install` itself.This way, you could have a single executable jar that serves the angular as well.For instance, consider the following project structure :

```
SampleMultiModuleProject
 |__SampleMultiModuleService
 |__SampleMultiModuleUI
```

In  this case, you will have three different pom files like as follows.

SampleMultiModuleProject main `pom.xml` : (where all main dependencies are present)

```
<modules>
    <module>SampleMultiModuleUI</module>
    <module>SampleMultiModuleService</module>
</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

//add rest of the dependencies here.

SampleMultiModuleService service `pom.xml` : (for service module and add the springboot maven plugin to make it executable with embedded tomcat, and add other dependencies that are needed in service module , for instance lombok)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and finally configure the ui  module to  build angular like SampleMultiModuleUI `pom.xml` :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>./</workingDirectory>
                <nodeVersion>v13.3.0</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>6.13.1</npmVersion>
                <nodeDownloadRoot>http://nodejs.org/dist/</nodeDownloadRoot>
                <npmDownloadRoot>http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/</npmDownloadRoot>
                <installDirectory>./</installDirectory>
                <npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>false</npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                  <configuration>
                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm run-script build-prod</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

So what happens is when you do maven clean install, it will trigger the build of the ui module which in turn uses the frontend builder to install a local npm which runs the command specified in the arguments. The `package.json` file in your angular application will by default contain something like :

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "stats": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
  },
```

So you are essentially calling this `ng build --prod` through this process.Also in `angular.json` set the `output path` as the resources folder under the service module in your project, so that the assets will be created there.

```
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "SampleMultiModuleUI": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../SampleMultiModuleService/src/main/resources/static",
       //rest of the config
```

Comment: @Mari090 I have provided an updated answer including samples .

Answer (score 0):

as i understand your question just create new file named `proxy.config.json` and paste below code in that file, place file next to `.angular-cli.json`

```
{
  "/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

for hitting url to backend server don't use `http://localhost:8080/administration` instead use `/administration` as we use `http://localhost:8080/` in our proxy file.
in `app.component.ts` file place below code in `ngOnInit()`

```
this.http.get('/adminisitration',someRequestOption).subscribe(res =>{
  console.log('happy...!');
})
```

start backend server: (tomcat on port `8080`) and

start frontend server: 
`ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json` open browser and type url `http://localhost:4200` you will see logs on server and client if any.

**NOTE:**
above ports are default as provided by spring boot and angular 4

Answer (score -2):

I think best way is to separate angular 4 app and java spring app.

In my case java spring app is API handling all requests from angular 4 app via proxy (angular-cli proxy -> easy to configure).

Angular 4 app on node.js, developed in visual studio code, and java spring on embedded tomcat (undertow) developed in eclipse. They can be on separated servers (eg. my angular 4 app is on localhost:4200 while java spring API is on http://mydomain.ch:8900)

If you need more info then add comment.

Hope in helps

PS. proxy is handled on client side (angular 4 app) not on server side (java spring)

Comment: The question is about how to integrate an Angular app with a spring boot stack. Your answer is the oposite of what he needs.