# Pass Angular environment variables to compiled static angular files in spring boot

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I am now using angular and spring boot to build website project. When we deploy, we will `ng build  --output-path=../spring-boot-project/src/main/resources/static",` angular and generate a static folder in spring boot, like `/resource/static`. Then we build and deploy a .jar file to our prod(or lab) environment.

so when we run the .jar file, how can we pass some environment varibles to angular part(the static files in spring boot project).

More specifically, I want to set angular environment in spring boot application.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"

---

spring:
  profiles: dev
angular.v1: "something1_dev"
angular.v2: "something2_dev"


---

spring:
  profiles: prod
angular.v1: "something1_prod"
angular.v2: "something2_prod"
```

how can I pass these values(different values because of different profiles) to angular side?

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249434/azure-devops-angular-environment-variables/59249554#59249554. So i would separate angular and spring unless you are using server side rendering

Comment: I am also facing this very same problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### Externalize configuration to separate file

Create a file `settings.js` in `assets` that shall hold your env variables:

```
const GlobalSettings = {
   ... your settings values
}
```

Add this file to your `index.html` so it will automatically be loaded during startup (but not packaged by Webpack).

```
<script src="assets/settings.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

In your code `GlobalSettings` would then be available - well - globally.

###### Inject content of `settings.js` into environment

If you prefer to work with the environment inside of your Angular app you could overwrite the specific properties of environment in `main.ts`:

```
environment.someProperty = GlobalSettings.someProperty;
... bootstrap Angular
```

Now you can change your settings by replacing `settings.js` instead of having to rebuild the whole app.

#### Edit file using environment variables

Use `envsubst` to replace variables in your `settings.js`

```
// settings.template.js
const GlobalSettings = {
  someProperty: "${SOME_PROPERTY}"
}

// command that starts your server, e.g. docker command
envsubst < settings.template.js > settings.js && <command to start webserver>
```

This will obviously not work if you ship your Angular app inside a Java jar.

#### Provide `settings.js` via Spring backend

Do not copy the file to the `static` directory (and thus not into the jar).

Instead create an endpoint in your Java app that listens on `/assets/settings.js`.
Here you can use all the Java/Spring magic (including reading env variables) to assemble `settings.js` with the desired content.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with what you are asking is that , once you place the  angular generated files under the static folder, springboot will treat the files as static assets and will not use any templating engine for us to bind any furthur data to the files. It will receive the request and if it matched the asset it will serve it directly.

For your use-case to work, you will have to set the angular environment in the angular build itself. What you could maybe do is,  have the angular build parameterized like using maven profiles so that you could control the angular build using maven command itself. You might probably be using the `front-end-builder` plugin to trigger the angular build right. So , in that case when you provide the `npm run-script` command you could provide which customized command you want to run by providing different commands in your `package.json`. For buid setup read : [How to integrate an Angular 4 app with a Spring Boot stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750276/how-to-integrate-an-angular-4-app-with-a-spring-boot-stack/60771725#60771725)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. right now I have already integrated angular with a spring boot stack, it works. my question: is there a way to pass angular environment variables to angular when the angular ui project already served as a static resource in spring boot.